# How to map all nodes of a Wikidata tag

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I am trying to get all the elements of the following Wikidata tag:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q31074657

As you can see, this tag corresponds to a Wikidata category of type *Statements* -> *Part of*, from a set of Catalonia mountains.

I tried something like that:

```
[out:json][timeout:60];
{{geocodeArea:"Catalunya"}}->.searchArea;
(
    node["brand:wikidata"="Q31074657"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
```

But return empty data

Comment: Seems there is no node with this tag in OpenStreetMap data. From wiki, only this page https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repte_dels_100_cims links to Q31074657. If your goal is to map all the summits from cawiki page, then easiest way would be to read the coordinates from the table.